# Ruby filtering specific lines from a text file

Tags: ruby

I'm a newbie! I have a text file that contains lines and lines of text. I want to try to create a code that only allows the lines that have the phrase "larry.bird" show while the others are deleted. This is my current code...

```
File.open("HM.txt").each do |line|
   puts line
   if line.include? "larry.bird"
      puts "larye.bird " + line
   end
end

File.readlines('HM.txt') do |li|
  puts li if (li['larry.bird'])
end
```

If you can help me out, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close. You're opening and reading the file correctly; you're just accidentally printing every line before performing the check. The `puts line` on the second line of your code is ensuring that this occurs.

```
File.open("HM.txt") do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    if line.include? "larry.bird"
      puts "larry.bird " + line
    end
  end
end
```

We can also shorten one-line if statements in Ruby, using suffix notation that often makes code more concise.

```
File.open("HM.txt") do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
    puts "larry.bird " + line if line.include? "larry.bird"
  end
end
```

This is equivalent to the first example.

Comment: IMO that one-line `if` gets lost in the noise (too many clauses to the left of it). Instead, since `each_line` returns an `Enumerator`, `each_line.reject { |line| line.include?(...) }.each { |line| puts ... }` is probably nicer.